How does Ramanujacharya and Madhavacharya interpret Bhagwatam 1.3.28?
The Gaudiya Sampradaya considers Krsna as the Supreme Personality of Godhead and scriptural reference to their claims often boils down to the "kṛṣṇas tu bhagavān svayam" verse found in the Srimad Bhagwatam 1.3.28.
Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada translates it as "All of the above-mentioned incarnations are either plenary portions or portions of the plenary portions of the Lord, but Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa is the original Personality of Godhead. All of them appear on planets whenever there is a disturbance created by the atheists. The Lord incarnates to protect the theists."
How does Ramanujacharya and Madhavacharya interpret this verse?

According to these acharyas, Lord Narayana incarnated as Lord Krishna and so "Krishna" and "Narayana" refer to the same person: God. Shri Narayana and Shri Krishna are abheda. According to Shri Madhvacharya, there is not even the slightest difference between the Lord on Earth and the Lord in Vaikuntha: in general, there is not even the slightest difference between any two roopas of Lord Vishnu
